# How to get values of queried table in hibernate?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have a query like this:

```
var query = scope.Session.QueryOver<Task>().Where(s => s.Code == code && s.Flag == flag && s.Antry != null);
```

I have a second query:

```
var personQuery = scope.Session.QueryOver<Person>();
```

The query has a field id, which corresponds to an id in the `personQuery`.

What I want is to make personQuery only contain ids that are present in the query. So far, I have been doing this:

```
int[] arr  = query.Where(i=> i.Id!=null).List<int>().ToArray();
entryQuery.Where(i => i.Id.IsIn(arr));
```

But, I think this will fail because I know that:

`query.Where(i=> i.Id!=null).List<int>().ToArray();`

will not return an integer array but an object of query.

So how can I only get the integer's id in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get only the integers id's from the query, you can select an anonymous type with only the properties you are interested in something like:

```
var integerids = scope.Session.QueryOver<Person>()
    .Select(p => p.Id)
    .List<int>();
```

Comment: lol... sorry, you must have taught that this is a very noob question... darn it... i always forget the difference of select and where